# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind') on AliExpress API using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the aliexpress-product-scraper NPM library to get product details on AliExpress. But I'm getting this error right now:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')
at 1777.../common/Debug.js (bundle.alisavetools.js:183218:50)
at o (bundle.alisavetools.js:1:265)
at bundle.alisavetools.js:1:316
at 1782.../common/Puppeteer.js (bundle.alisavetools.js:184542:29)
at o (bundle.alisavetools.js:1:265)
at bundle.alisavetools.js:1:316
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.alisavetools.js:183047:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.alisavetools.js:183071:4)
at 1775../node/Puppeteer.js (bundle.alisavetools.js:183071:17)
at o (bundle.alisavetools.js:1:265)
```

Here is my JS code:

```js
const scrape = require('aliexpress-product-scraper');
const product = scrape('32958933105');

product.then(res => {
  console.log('The JSON: ', res);
});
```

I just need to see the JSON data first on the console but I can't proceed because of the error. Hoping you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: seems to be working on my end with the code snippet you pasted. what's your version of node?

Comment: My node version is v.14.15.3

Comment: Hi @MuradAli, what's your node version?

Comment: my node version is v12.22.10

Comment: Ow, so the higher version affects my code?

Comment: maybe. give it a go with an older version and see if it works.

Comment: Hi @Ali, I already used v.12.22.10, but this is the I got:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[^\ä¸€-é¾ \ã-ã‚”\ã‚¡-ãƒ´ãƒ¼\w\.\-]+/: Range out of order in character class (at ${ExecutionContext_js_1.EVALUATION_SCRIPT_URL}`,:32239:48)

Comment: Hi @Ali, what did you do to make it work? Can you share it here? :) Thank you.

Comment: just did npm install for the library and it worked for me without complications. im guessing there could be a difference of the environment or something on your side.